# Setting macro-variable-value in macro-function C++

Tags: c++, macros

I need to call a function which call a macro-function to change macro-value in runtime.

This code isn't compiled:

```
#define MY_MACRO 32
#define SET_MY_MACRO_VAL(IS_TRUE)(MY_MACRO=(IS_TRUE)?16:U32)
```

In function `SET_MY_MACRO_VAL`

```
> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

    #define SET_MY_MACRO_VAL(IS_TRUE)(MY_MACRO=(IS_TRUE)?16:U32)
                                          ^
    in expansion of macro 'SET_MY_MACRO_VAL'
         SET_MY_MACRO_VAL(True);
         ^
```

Comment: there are no macros at runtime. Macros are expanded even before compilation

Comment: Is `IS_TRUE` known at compile time? If not I'm afraid using the preprocessor is a non-starter

Comment: There are no such things as macro-functions or macro-variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro value are replaced BEFORE compile time by the preprocessor and do not exist at run time.

It is not a variable it is simply a way of using text for the value "32".

If you do this :

```
#define MY_MACRO 32
#define SET_MY_MACRO_VAL(IS_TRUE)(MY_MACRO=(IS_TRUE)?16:U32)
```

It will be expanded to this

```
#define MY_MACRO 32
#define SET_MY_MACRO_VAL(IS_TRUE)(32=(IS_TRUE)?16:U32)
```

What you can do is use a #define

```
#ifdef SET_MACRO_VAL_32
#define MY_MACRO 32
#else
#define MY_MACRO 16
#endif
```

Or use a conditionnal macro if you prefer

```
#if (IS_TRUE>0)
#define MY_MACRO 32
#else
#define MY_MACRO 16
#endif
```

Edit : 
In C++, you shouldn't really need macro though. You can use template and / or constexpr variable for compile-time value. In C++17 you can even use `constexpr if`.

Comment: ..or not use macros at all

Comment: Yes but the question was about macro :). In C++ template and/or constexpr are way better and cleaner

Comment: one could also read the question as "how to call function to change  a value at runtime" ;) dont worry, you got my upvote already